# ip6tables only allow packages to a certain ip-range

Tags: linux, iptables, ipv6, rules

I am trying to configure ip6tables to only allow ssh connections to a specific range.
In iptables the command would be:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m iprange --dst-range 192.168.178.0-192.168.178.254
```

But according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ip6tables) the option -m iprange seems to be gone.
What would be the correct command to achieve such behavior ?
As always any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: What is the range you are trying to limit to? Replace your prefix with 2001:db8 (example net) if you're concerned about revealing your actual addresses.

Comment: You're not likely to need iprange, as you can just specify a netblock directly.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the `ip6tables` man page on CentOS 6 and Debian 7 and they both include `iprange`:

```
iprange
   This matches on a given arbitrary range of IP addresses.

   [!] --src-range from[-to]
          Match source IP in the specified range.

   [!] --dst-range from[-to]
          Match destination IP in the specified range.
```

The man page for `iptables-extensions` on ArchLinux also indicates that `iprange` should exist.

A quick test on a CentOS 6 box shows that it does work:

```
www1 $ sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -m iprange --dst-range 2001:db8::1-2001:db8::ff -j LOG
[sudo] password for fukawi2: 
www1  $ sudo ip6tables -nvL OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 LOG        tcp      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                tcp dpt:22 destination IP range 2001:db8::1-2001:db8::ff LOG flags 0 level 4
```

Have you looked at your actual man page instead of an online one?